# Flutter XCode Error: Null objc class data for '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_MLKBarcode

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, xcode15

Im currently trying to deploy a Flutter App from a 2019 MacBook Pro (MacOS Sonoma 14.0 Beta) onto a iPhone 12 Pro (iOS 17.0 Beta) while using XCode 15 Beta 4 when I get this error.

```
Null objc class data for '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_MLKBarcode' in ‘Flutter Project Location/ios/Pods/MLKitBarcodeScanning/Frameworks/MLKitBarcodeScanning.framework/MLKitBarcodeScanning'
```

Also, I get another error:

```
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with XCode Beta, or just something else as this error just came up after I upgraded from Ventura to Sonoma.

Comment: Same here, with the same library on macOS Ventura.

Comment: same here with macOS Ventura